# phantomjs: how to make fs.open behave the same as require, for paths

Tags: phantomjs

`require()` works based on the script path. `fs.open()` works on the invocation (current shell) path.

Let's say i have the tree:

```
dirA/
dirA/dirB/
dirA/dirB/dirC/
dirA/dirB/dirC/test.js
dirA/dirB/dirC2/include_me.js
dirA/dirB/dirC2/open_me.js
```

and the contents for `test.js`:

```
var myMod = require('../dirC2/include_me.js');
var fs = require('fs');
fs.open('../dirC2/open_me.js')
```

Regardless of the current path I am when i execute `phantomjs $PATH/test.js` the require will succeed, and the fs.open will fail (unless `$PATH` is `dirC`)

Is there any way to make `fs.open()` behave as `require()`?

I'm thinking something like `fs.open( phantomjs.getScriptPath() + '../dirC2/open_me.js' );`
 but my searchfoo failed to find anything to fill in for the made-up `getScriptPath` method there.

---

Edit:
posting here the workaround i'm using in case the answer is "No".

```
/**
 * Opens a file relative to the script path.
 * this solves an inconsistency between require() and fs.open()
*/
exports.getScriptPath = function( newPath ){
    var script, scriptPath;
    script = exports.system.args[0];
    scriptPath = script.replace(/\/[^\/]+$/, '') // removes everything from 
    //                                              the last "/" until the end of
    //                                              the line, non-greedy
    return scriptPath + '/';
}
```

this is used in a utility module i have. Also it assumes you are calling a script (won't work well if you use said module in an interactive phantomjs session) and unix style paths. if you're using windows, just add `\` to the regexp. then it's used like:

```
filehandle = exports.fs.open( exports.getScriptPath() + '../dirC2/open_me.js', 'r' );
```